# Is passing an "&" as a string character possible using the openFDA API? If no, is there a way to access data with manufacturer name containing "&"?

Tags: openfda

I am using the openFDA NDC API. Searching and counting using the "manufacture_name.exact" field results in a status 400 bad request when passing the character "&" as part of the manufacturer name.

I am using the fetch API and JavaScript. The code is provided below; where "${manufacturer}" may be exactly:  "The Procter & Gamble Manufacturing Company"

```
const manufacturerResponse = await fetch(`${this.ndcBaseEndpoint}?${this.apiKey}&search=openfda.manufacturer_name.exact:${manufacturer}&limit=10`)
```

I have reviewed [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16211/what-characters-are-allowed-in-the-search-parameter-of-the-ndc-openfda-api-reque)  where an answer by Nag lists the supported characters and & is not on that list.

I have tried using %26 as a replacement without success.

Is there a method to search with & inside the manufacturer name? If not, is there a reliable way to access the data which has "&" in the manufacturer's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed:

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.manufacturer_name.exact:%22The%20Procter%20%26%20Gamble%20Manufacturing%20Company%22

Sorry about the inconvenience.